# Include SVG asset as component in React

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

I was using the normal way to display an SVG asset, e.g.

```
import pic from "../assets/pic.svg";
const myPic = () => <img src={pic}/>;
```

This works as `pic` becomes the path to the svg picture.

Now I want to make the picture response to its background colour to change its fill colour. I have tried the CSS way to change the `fill` property, which works, but only when I have the svg content inline instead of setting it as an `img` `src`, e.g.

```
const myPic = () => <svg>.....</svg>;
```

My question is, if I still want to import the svg picture from assets folder (because the svg picture is quite big I don't want to put it inline), the first method above would return a path instead of the content of the svg as string, so how do you import an svg asset as string? Or feel free to suggest alternatives to achieve displaying an svg with dynamic contrast colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is different depending on which toolchain you are using.
If you are using Create React App:

```js
import { ReactComponent as Pic} from '../assets/pic.svg';

// code omitted...

// Use it like normal components
return <Pic />;
```

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files

Do inform me if you are using a different toolchain.

Comment: Hey that works, where is this `ReactComponent` coming from in the svg file that has only "<svg>...</svg>" in it?

Comment: I believe CRA handled it internally. I'm not sure about the details